# Navigator not working in React Native App (Argument 0 (NSNumber))

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get navigation between views to work in React Native like so:

```
newUserFlow() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: "Create Account",
      component: F8InfoView,
    });
  }

<TopFiveButton
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.newUserFlow.bind(this)}
            caption="Create Account"
/>
```

However, I am running into this error on click:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:75 Argument 0 (NSNumber) of RCTNavigatorManager.requestSchedulingJavaScriptNavigation must not be null
```

This worked previously, but something seems to have changed.  What could be the issue?

The debugger references this in the exceptions manageR:

```
  // Flow doesn't like it when you set arbitrary values on a global object
  (console: any)._errorOriginal = console.error.bind(console);
```

am I breaking something in flow?

### Edit

index.ios.js looks like this:

```
class nomad extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Nomad',
          component: LoginScreen
        }} />
    );
  }
};
```

then in LoginScreen:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  newUserFlow() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: "Create Account",
      component: F8InfoView,
//      passProps: {userInfo: this.props.userInfo}
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
          <F8Button
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.newUserFlow.bind(this)}
            caption="Create Account"
          />
    );
  }
}
```

Clicking the button gives me the error.

Comment: What does your `renderScene` look like in your `Navigator`?

Comment: I'm not using the Navigator component in the render() function.  I am simply calling that function (newUserFlow()), and pushing to the component F8InfoView, using the   this.props.navigator.push command.

Comment: it's a button.  I already initialized the app with a component view using NavigatorIOS.

Comment: @rclai any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to help because I have never used NavigatorIOS.

Comment: Can you try following? `onPress={()=> this.newUserFlow()}`

Comment: @ShukarullahShah I just tried it.  It didn't work.  Same error :/

Comment: I have a working example [here](https://github.com/ghamaide/Demo), check it out and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: What version of RN are you using?

Comment: What's the rest of the error stack? Whatever is calling RCTNavigatorManager.requestSchedulingJavaScriptNavigation is not including any parameter to satisfy the nonnull NSNumber * requirement in RCTNavigatorManager.m

Comment: A react native routing package (`react-native-router-flux`) may help you. I use it and it is awesome to get things done. Can be found here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using for react ? Are you sure to be on the last stable version ? I ask you that because in [ExceptionsManager.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/JavaScriptAppEngine/Initialization/ExceptionsManager.js), I cannot see "NSNumber" on line 75...

Let me underline that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738194/using-navigator-to-move-from-one-view-to-the-next-in-react-native-app) is very similar...  so have you tried to put

```
navigator.push(routes[1]);
```

inside the onPress prop. ?

something like:

```
<F8Button onPress={
    () => { if (route.index === 0){ 
                    navigator.push(routes[1]); 
                } else {
                    navigator.pop(); 
                } 
          }
...
...
```

To conclude you may also have a closer look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Hope this solution helps you a bit

**Problems which might have occured**

The problem was that once you execute the `onPressevent`, the i index is beyond bounds so the node can't be found.
Something tells me this happened because you were trying to access a ref that is null because you put the `dropdown` list in the `renderScene` function of a navigator. I had the exact same problem.

Please consider posting your code or debugging the `findNodeHandle` result, because this error is produced once you send null as a node.

The error may br due to React being unable to find the node because `findNodeHandle` doesn't get a React node as a parameter.

It may be the problem that you are sending a null node to the event. Try to debug what you're getting in the `findNodeHandle` function.

**Solutions**

You have to change all the refs to `this.refs.navigator.refs['any reference made in your code']` etc.

Don't forget to give the actual navigator a ref

```
<Navigator
ref='navigator'
```