# Using Navigator to move from one view to the next in React-Native app

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make sense of the f8app: https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app

In it, it has a section dedicated to Navigation:F8Navigator.js

It looks like:

```
var F8Navigator = React.createClass({
  _handlers: ([]: Array<() => boolean>),

  componentDidMount: function() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  },

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      addBackButtonListener: this.addBackButtonListener,
      removeBackButtonListener: this.removeBackButtonListener,
    };
  },

  addBackButtonListener: function(listener) {
    this._handlers.push(listener);
  },

  removeBackButtonListener: function(listener) {
    this._handlers = this._handlers.filter((handler) => handler !== listener);
  },

  handleBackButton: function() {
    for (let i = this._handlers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (this._handlers[i]()) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    const {navigator} = this.refs;
    if (navigator && navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
      navigator.pop();
      return true;
    }

    if (this.props.tab !== 'schedule') {
      this.props.dispatch(switchTab('schedule'));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        ref="navigator"
        style={styles.container}
        configureScene={(route) => {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
          }
          // TODO: Proper scene support
          if (route.shareSettings || route.friend) {
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
          } else {
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom;
          }
        }}
        initialRoute={{}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  },

  renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    if (route.allSessions) {
      return (
        <SessionsCarousel
          {...route}
          navigator={navigator}
        />
      );
    }
    if (route.session) {
      return (
        <SessionsCarousel
          session={route.session}
          navigator={navigator}
        />
      );
    }
    if (route.filter) {
      return (
        <FilterScreen navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
    if (route.friend) {
      return (
        <FriendsScheduleView
          friend={route.friend}
          navigator={navigator}
        />
      );
    }
    if (route.login) {
      return (
        <LoginModal
          navigator={navigator}
          onLogin={route.callback}
        />
      );
    }
    if (route.share) {
      return (
        <SharingSettingsModal navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
    if (route.shareSettings) {
      return <SharingSettingsScreen navigator={navigator} />;
    }
    if (route.rate) {
      return <RatingScreen navigator={navigator} surveys={route.surveys} />;
    }
    if (route.notices) {
      return <ThirdPartyNotices navigator={navigator} />;
    }
    return <F8TabsView navigator={navigator} />;
  },
});

F8Navigator.childContextTypes = {
  addBackButtonListener: React.PropTypes.func,
  removeBackButtonListener: React.PropTypes.func,
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});

function select(store) {
  return {
    tab: store.navigation.tab,
    isLoggedIn: store.user.isLoggedIn || store.user.hasSkippedLogin,
  };
}

module.exports = connect(select)(F8Navigator);
```

What I would like to do, is very simply take a button in a component I have:

```
      <F8Button
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={}
        caption="Create Account"
      />
```

and navigate to another component view when it is pressed.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Navigator documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) you can see that inside the `onPress` prop you have to put `navigator.push(routes[1]);` or w/e way you defined your routes.